# Why it is necessary to update /etc/default/grub, and not just save it?

Tags: grub2

I understand that the grub file contains some instructions that are required before booting such as: booting in text or booting in Graphics mode.

My question is why do I need `update-grub`? Why just saving the file after making changes would not work?

Answer (score 6):

`update-grub` generates grub's `grub.cfg` file, which grub reads at boot, based on grub's configuration in `/etc/default/grub`. (Grub doesn't read `/etc/default/grub` at boot).

Excerpt from [Ubuntu Wiki, Grub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2):

> The main Grub 2 configuration file, normally located in the `/boot/grub` folder, is grub.cfg. It is the product of various scripts and should not normally be edited directly.
>
> `grub.cfg` is overwritten by certain Grub 2 package updates, whenever a kernel is added or removed, or when the user runs `update-grub`